# Update() method doesn't work with ORACLE database

Tags: java, spring, sql-server-2008, oracle10g, jdbctemplate

I don't know why the update() method doesn't work with ORACLE database

> ```
> deleteQuery = "delete from USBRPF where upper(userid) = upper(?)" ;
>
> String s= "ABC " ;
> getJdbcTemplate().update(deleteQuery, s.trim());
> ```

There's a row with column USERID having data 'ABC    ' (there's some spaces character after 'C' character)

It seems to not find out that row.

However, if I change code to below, it works

> ```
> deleteQuery = "delete from USBRPF where upper(userid) like upper(?)" ;
> String s= "ABC " ;
> getJdbcTemplate().update(deleteQuery, s.trim() +  "%");
> ```

or

> ```
> deleteQuery = "delete from USBRPF where upper(trim(userid)) = upper(?)" ;
> String s= "ABC " ;
> getJdbcTemplate().update(deleteQuery, s.trim());
> ```

Note: all works with MSSQL database, with data migrated from ORACLE.
I guess there's problem with database setting. Could have someone figure it out? Thanks

MODIFIED:

Column information:

ORACLE

```
  BRANCH    CHAR(2 CHAR)          
  COMPANY   CHAR(1 CHAR)         
  DATIME    TIMESTAMP(6)          
  JOBNM CHAR(10 CHAR)          
  UNIQUE_NUMBER NUMBER(18,0)    
  USERID    CHAR(10 CHAR)         
  USRPRF    CHAR(10 CHAR)
```

MSSQL

```
[UNIQUE_NUMBER] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,    
[USERID] [nchar](10) NULL,  
[COMPANY] [nchar](1) NULL,  
[BRANCH] [nchar](2) NULL,   
[USRPRF] [nchar](10) NULL,  
[JOBNM] [nchar](10) NULL,   
[DATIME] [datetime2](6)> NULL,
```

Comment: I've never used Oracle but you probably need to include the exact datatype used by Oracle and SQL/Server for the column to get an answer. Personally I wouldn't have expected it to work in SQL/Server either when you trim the search string but it's in the data, but then again don't use JDBC.

Comment: @PeterJ: I added datatype used by Oracle and SQL/Server

Comment: What exactly does *not work* mean? Do you get an error? Is nothing deleted? Are too many rows deleted? Btw: using `CHAR` is a bad choice due to the automatic padding that is applied. I'm pretty sure you actually want `VARCHAR` instead (for both DBMS).

Answer (score 2):

CHAR is a fixed length type. So even if your data looks like "ABC" in the database, it's stored as "ABC       ".  CHAR columns will be [padded with spaces up their size](http://psoug.org/definition/CHAR.htm).

Therefore on the first example you're comparing "ABC       " (as stored in the DB) to "ABC" (as passed from Java after the trim() call).  On your second and third example you're working around this.

I would recommend that you use VARCHAR2  since it's more natural and more commonly used.  If not possible, you could try padding the value that you pass from Java up to the CHAR size as defined in Oracle.